# Shared STL objects using Boost library during a fork()

Tags: c++, boost, ipc, shared-memory, boost-interprocess

I tried sharing STL objects (like an unordered map for example).

I read that we can use Boost Library for this process of easily using shared memory between processes.
I used the codes given [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/interprocess/allocators_containers.html#interprocess.allocators_containers.additional_containers.unordered).

The writer code is like this:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>

#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>     //boost::unordered_map
#include <functional>                  //std::equal_to
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>   //boost::hash

int main ()
{
   using namespace boost::interprocess;
   //Remove shared memory on construction and destruction
   struct shm_remove
   {
      shm_remove() { shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
      ~shm_remove(){ shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
   } remover;

   //Create shared memory
   managed_shared_memory segment(create_only, "MySharedMemory", 65536);

   //Note that unordered_map<Key, MappedType>'s value_type is std::pair<const Key, MappedType>,
   //so the allocator must allocate that pair.
   typedef int    KeyType;
   typedef float  MappedType;
   typedef std::pair<const int, float> ValueType;

   //Typedef the allocator
   typedef allocator<ValueType, managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> ShmemAllocator;

   //Alias an unordered_map of ints that uses the previous STL-like allocator.
   typedef boost::unordered_map
      < KeyType               , MappedType
      , boost::hash<KeyType>  ,std::equal_to<KeyType>
      , ShmemAllocator>
   MyHashMap;

   //Construct a shared memory hash map.
   //Note that the first parameter is the initial bucket count and
   //after that, the hash function, the equality function and the allocator
   MyHashMap *myhashmap = segment.construct<MyHashMap>("MyHashMap")  //object name
      ( 3, boost::hash<int>(), std::equal_to<int>()                  //
      , segment.get_allocator<ValueType>());                         //allocator instance

   //Insert data in the hash map
   for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i){
      myhashmap->insert(ValueType(i, (float)i*23.5));
   }

   MyHashMap :: iterator iter;
   iter = myhashmap->begin();

   std::cout << "Hoooo.... i am in the server!!\n";

   for (; iter != myhashmap->end(); iter++) {
      std::cout << iter->first << " " << iter->second << "\n";
   }


   return 0;
}
```

And the reader code is like this:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>

#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>     //boost::unordered_map
#include <functional>                  //std::equal_to
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>   //boost::hash

int main ()
{
   using namespace boost::interprocess;
   //Remove shared memory on construction and destruction
   // struct shm_remove
   // {
   //    shm_remove() { shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
   //    ~shm_remove(){ shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
   // } remover;

   //Create shared memory
   managed_shared_memory segment(open_only, "MySharedMemory");

   //Note that unordered_map<Key, MappedType>'s value_type is std::pair<const Key, MappedType>,
   //so the allocator must allocate that pair.
   typedef int    KeyType;
   typedef float  MappedType;
   typedef std::pair<const int, float> ValueType;

   //Typedef the allocator
   typedef allocator<ValueType, managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> ShmemAllocator;

   //Alias an unordered_map of ints that uses the previous STL-like allocator.
   typedef boost::unordered_map
      < KeyType               , MappedType
      , boost::hash<KeyType>  ,std::equal_to<KeyType>
      , ShmemAllocator>
   MyHashMap;

   //Construct a shared memory hash map.
   //Note that the first parameter is the initial bucket count and
   //after that, the hash function, the equality function and the allocator
   MyHashMap *myhashmap = segment.find<MyHashMap>("MyHashMap").first;  //object name
      // ( 3, boost::hash<int>(), std::equal_to<int>()                  //
      // , segment.get_allocator<ValueType>());                         //allocator instance


   MyHashMap :: iterator iter;
   std::cout << "in client e\n";
   iter = myhashmap->begin();

   std::cout << "Hoooo.... i am in the client!!\n";

   for (; iter != myhashmap->end(); iter++) {
      std::cout << iter->first << " " << iter->second << "\n";
   }

   segment.destroy<MyHashMap>("MyHashMap");


   return 0;
}
```

I verified that the data is being added to the shared map by printing it in the writer part.

But when I run the reader code, I get the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::interprocess::interprocess_exception'
  what():  No such file or directory
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I am not understanding the error that I am making, as I am completely new to the Boost library and came across it for one of my projects.

I also wanted to know if I can include the reader part in one of the processes created using a `fork()` (as I had tried the same earlier and was getting the same error).

Comment: Did you manage to solve?

Comment: @aprospero Sorry, but I couldn't solve it that way. Instead, I used an alternative way (which worked) where only the parent process would host all the data structures, and child processes would send `SIGNAL`s and minimal data through `named pipe`s to enable data updates. Hope it helps!